# Use scipy to define a monte carlo sampling ellipse in the xy plane

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, montecarlo, scientific-computing

Starting from a large set of points in the x--y plane, I would like to select a subset of these points such that are preferentially in a way that is defined by an ellipse with known major and minor axis. For example:

```
import numpy as np 

npts = int(1e5)
lim = 3
x = np.random.uniform(-lim, lim, npts)
y = np.random.uniform(-lim, lim, npts)

major_axis = np.array((1, 1))
minor_axis = np.array((-0.25, 0.25))
```

The above two vectors define an ellipse with 4-1 axis ratio with major axis pointing along the line y = x. So I am trying to write down a Monte Carlo sampling algorithm whereby if a point in the x--y plane lies on the input major axis (in this case the line y=x), it has an enhanced probability of being selected over a point lying on the minor axis (in this case the line y = -x), where the probability enhancement factor is simply determined by the major-to-minor axis ratio (so a factor of 4 in this case).

I have been trying to do this using the `pdf` method of `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal`, but I think I must be using the method improperly. The way I'm going about it is to define the covariance matrix by treating the major and minor axes as the eigendirections, use the `pdf` method on each point, sort these probabilities, and select the top `Nselect` of those probabilities.

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
cov = np.array((major_axis, minor_axis))
p = np.vstack((x, y)).T
prob_select = multivariate_normal.pdf(p, cov=cov)
idx_select = np.argsort(prob_select)
Nselect = len(x)/10
result_x = x[idx_select][-Nselect:]
result_y = y[idx_select][-Nselect:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
__=ax.scatter(result_x, result_y, s=1)
xlim = ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ylim = ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
```

[image: incorrect distribution]

The above plot shows that something is incorrect in my algorithm, since the major axis of this ellipse does not lie on the line y=x. My suspicion was the covariance matrix is not defined correctly, but when I use the same covariance matrix with the `rvs` method, I get the expected distribution:

```
correct_result = multivariate_normal.rvs(size=Nselect, cov=cov)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
__=ax.scatter(correct_result[:, 0], correct_result[:, 1], s=1)
xlim = ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
ylim = ax.set_ylim(-3, 3)
```

[image: expected distribution from <code>rvs</code>]

Is there a simple mistake I am making in my usage of `multivariate_normal.pdf` or covariance matrix definition? If the algorithm is flawed in some other way, is there a simpler way to define such a selection function starting from major/minor axes of an ellipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why the results are inconsistent

The covariance matrix is ill-formed here, and you can make no inferences from the resulting behavior. The fact that the `rvs` method gives different results in this case is merely a reflection of the fact that the `rvs` and `pdf` functions preprocess their arguments differently. Whereas [`rvs`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L384) basically passes its parameters straight to `numpy.multivariate_normal`...

```
# https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L405
dim, mean, cov = _process_parameters(None, mean, cov)
out = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size)
return _squeeze_output(out)
```

[`pdf`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L358) passes the covariance matrix to a function that calculates the pseudo-inverse:

```
# https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L378
dim, mean, cov = _process_parameters(None, mean, cov)
x = _process_quantiles(x, dim)
prec_U, log_det_cov = _psd_pinv_decomposed_log_pdet(cov)
out = np.exp(self._logpdf(x, mean, prec_U, log_det_cov))
return _squeeze_output(out)
```

These are only guaranteed to give consistent results if the covariance matrix is well formed.

#### Building a well formed matrix

A covariance matrix is just the covariance of each of the corresponding pairings of dimensions, so it's by definition symmetric.

The docs reiterate this:

> **cov** : 2-D array_like, of shape (N, N)
>
> Covariance matrix of the distribution. It must be symmetric and positive-semidefinite for proper sampling.

Given that you want to get a covariance matrix from major and minor axes, what you really want is to solve a reverse eigenvector problem! Yay! I wish we had mathjax...

We need a symmetric matrix `C = [[a, b], [b, a]]` such that `[1, 1]` and `[1, -1]` are eigenvectors, and we also want the ratio of eigenvalues to be four-to-one. That means `C * [1, 1] = [4, 4]` and `C * [1, -1] = [1, -1]`. Picking 1 as our minor index eigenvalue and 4 as our major index eigenvalue, and doing the matrix multiplication by hand, using variables, we get `a + b = 4` and `a - b = 1`. So A is 2.5 and b is 1.5, and C is `[[2.5, 1.5], [1.5, 2.5]]`.

We can also use matrix equations to find a more direct solution. If `E` is the matrix of eigenvectors `[[1, 1], [1, -1]]` and `lambda` is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues `[[4, 0], [0, 1]]`, then we are looking for the matrix `X` such that:

```
X @ E = E @ lambda
```

Where `@` indicates matrix multiplication (as in Python 3.5+).

That means

```
X = E @ lambda @ E ^ -1
```

In `numpy` that's

```
>>> E = numpy.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])
>>> lambda_ = numpy.array([[4, 0], [0, 1]])
>>> E @ lambda_ @ numpy.linalg.pinv(E)
array([[ 2.5,  1.5],
       [ 1.5,  2.5]])
```

Using this as `cov` in your code gives the following:

[image: Chart of a correctly skewed ellipse.]

Comment: Wow. Exemplary answer, @senderle. Crystal clear in both the linear algebra explanation and also the implementation.